# Entity Framework performance after SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, sqlbulkcopy

I need some performance for doing some of my things. I'm trying to import excel data to my SQL Server database here is my code for doing that work but it really takes too much time for that. Could you give me some advice for that

```
   [WebMethod]
    public static string VerileriAktar(string alanlar, string gruplar, string shit)
    {
        ArtiDBEntities entity = new ArtiDBEntities();
        string[] eslesmeler = alanlar.Split(',');
        string[] grplar = gruplar.Split(',');

        DataSet ds = (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["ExcelVerileri"];
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["" + shit + ""];
        MembershipUser gelen = (MembershipUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["kimo"];
        Guid aa = (Guid)gelen.ProviderUserKey;


        List<tbl_AltMusteriler> bulkliste = new List<tbl_AltMusteriler>();
        List<tbl_AltMusteriler> ilkkontrol = entity.tbl_AltMusteriler.Where(o => o.UserId == aa).ToList();
        List<tbl_AltMusteriler> grupicin = new List<tbl_AltMusteriler>();
        List<tbl_OzelAlanlar> ensonatilacakalan = new List<tbl_OzelAlanlar>();
        List<tbl_OzelTarihler> ensonalicaktarih = new List<tbl_OzelTarihler>();

        // Datatable mın Kolon isimlerini değiştirdim.
        foreach (string item_col_name in eslesmeler)
        {
            string alan = item_col_name.Split('=')[0].Split('_')[1];
            string degisecek = item_col_name.Split('=')[1];
            if (degisecek == "")
                continue;
            dt.Columns[degisecek].ColumnName = alan;
        }



        #region verilerde

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            tbl_AltMusteriler yeni = new tbl_AltMusteriler();


            foreach (DataColumn dtclm in dt.Columns)
            {
                string gsm1 = "";
                if (dtclm.ColumnName == "gsm1")
                    gsm1 = dr["gsm1"].ToString();

                string gsm2 = "";
                if (dtclm.ColumnName == "gsm2")
                    gsm2 = dr["gsm2"].ToString();
                string ad = "";
                if (dtclm.ColumnName == "ad")
                    ad = dr["ad"].ToString();
                string soyad = "";
                if (dtclm.ColumnName == "soyad")
                    soyad = dr["soyad"].ToString();

                if (gsm1 != "")
                {
                    if (Tools.isNumber(gsm1) == false)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        if (gsm1.Length > 10)
                            gsm1 = gsm1.Substring(1, 10);
                        yeni.Gsm1 = gsm1;

                    }
                }

                if (gsm2 != "")
                {
                    if (Tools.isNumber(gsm2) == false)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        if (gsm2.Length > 10)
                            gsm2 = gsm2.Substring(1, 10);
                        yeni.Gsm2 = gsm2;
                    }
                }

                if (ad != "")
                    yeni.Ad = ad;
                if (soyad != "")
                    yeni.Soyad = soyad;
            }

            yeni.UserId = new Guid(aa.ToString());

            if (yeni.Gsm1 != "")
                grupicin.Add(yeni);               

        }
        #endregion



        bulkliste = grupicin.GroupBy(cust => cust.Gsm1).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();          

        List<tbl_AltMusteriler> yokartikin = bulkliste.Where(o => !ilkkontrol.Any(p => o.Gsm1 == p.Gsm1)).ToList();

        int saybakim = yokartikin.Count();

        DataTable bulkdt = new DataTable();
        if (yokartikin.Count > 0)
        {
            Type listType = yokartikin.ElementAt(0).GetType();             
            PropertyInfo[] properties = listType.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                if (property.Name == "UserId")
                    bulkdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = property.Name, DataType = typeof(Guid) });
                else
                    bulkdt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = property.Name });
            foreach (object itembulk in yokartikin)
            {
                DataRow drbk = bulkdt.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn col in bulkdt.Columns)
                    drbk[col] = listType.GetProperty(col.ColumnName).GetValue(itembulk, null);
                bulkdt.Rows.Add(drbk);
            }
        }


        //var rowsOnlyInDt1 = bulkdt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !bulkdt44.AsEnumerable()
        //        .Any(r2 => r["gsm1"].ToString() == r2["gsm1"].ToString()));

        //DataTable result = rowsOnlyInDt1.CopyToDataTable();//The third table

        if (bulkdt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArtiDBMemberShip"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction = null;
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                    using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_AltMusteriler";
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserId", "UserId");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ad", "Ad");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Soyad", "Soyad");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Adres", "Adres");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Gsm1", "Gsm1");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Gsm2", "Gsm2");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Faks", "Faks");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Telefonis", "Telefonis");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Telefonev", "Telefonev");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Eposta", "Eposta");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DogumTarihi", "DogumTarihi");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("EvlilikTar", "EvlilikTar");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TcNo", "TcNo");
                        //sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Deleted", "Deleted");
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(bulkdt);

                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }

            }

            entity.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (grplar.Length > 0)
        {
            List<tbl_AltMusteriler> guncelliste = entity.tbl_AltMusteriler.Where(o => o.UserId == aa).ToList();
            List<tbl_KisiGrup> kisigruplari = new List<tbl_KisiGrup>();
            foreach (tbl_AltMusteriler itemblkliste in bulkliste)
            {
                long AltMusteriIDsi = guncelliste.Where(o => o.Gsm1 == itemblkliste.Gsm1).FirstOrDefault().AltMusteriID;

                // Seçili Gruplara kişileri ekleme
                #region Gruplara ekleme


                if (grplar.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string item_gruplar in grplar)
                    {
                        if (item_gruplar == "chkall")
                            continue;
                        if (item_gruplar == "")
                            continue;
                        if (item_gruplar == null)
                            continue;

                        tbl_KisiGrup yeni_kisi_grup = new tbl_KisiGrup()
                        {
                            AltMusteriID = AltMusteriIDsi,
                            GrupID = int.Parse(item_gruplar)
                        };
                        kisigruplari.Add(yeni_kisi_grup);
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }

            List<tbl_KisiGrup> guncel_grup = entity.tbl_KisiGrup.Where(o => o.tbl_AltMusteriler.UserId == aa).ToList();

            List<tbl_KisiGrup> kisi_grup_kaydet = kisigruplari.Where(o => !guncel_grup.Any(p => o.AltMusteriID == p.AltMusteriID && o.GrupID == p.GrupID)).ToList();

            // Grupları Datatable çevirme
            #region Grupları Datatable le çevirme
            DataTable bulkdt2 = new DataTable();



            if (kisi_grup_kaydet.Count > 0)
            {
                Type listType = kisi_grup_kaydet.ElementAt(0).GetType();
                //Get element properties and add datatable columns  
                PropertyInfo[] properties = listType.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                    bulkdt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = property.Name });
                foreach (object itembulk in kisi_grup_kaydet)
                {
                    DataRow drbk = bulkdt2.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in bulkdt2.Columns)
                        drbk[col] = listType.GetProperty(col.ColumnName).GetValue(itembulk, null);
                    bulkdt2.Rows.Add(drbk);
                }
            }
            #endregion


            //Burada bulk insert işlemini gerçekleştiriyoruz...
            #region Grup Verileri BulkCopy ile birkerede yazdık

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArtiDBMemberShip"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction = null;
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                    using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
                    {
                        sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tbl_KisiGrup";
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("AltMusteriID", "AltMusteriID");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("GrupID", "GrupID");
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(bulkdt2);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }

            }

            entity.SaveChanges();
            #endregion


        }

        return "ok";

    }
```

**EDIT**

actually that codeblock takes time when if there is 70.000 or more rows data

```
List<tbl_AltMusteriler> yokartikin = bulkliste.Where(o => !ilkkontrol.Any(p => o.Gsm1 == p.Gsm1)).ToList();
```

I think the my main problem is while I'm just inserting data with `sqlbulkcopy`. After that I couldn't get the identity ids, for that reason I get data to a generic list and try to find that new ids and creating a new list of group. and `sqlbulkcopy` again. these are takes lots of time about 10 minutes to import 65.000 rows is there another way to do those things

Comment: Please try to reduce that code sample to something manageable. That's a *lot* to go through, and most of it does not seem to have anything to do with your use of Entity Framework. Additionally, have you done any testing to determine what call or calls are actually taking longer than they should?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. I would recomment reading [performance considerations for EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx). Also keep in mind that EF is not really meant for bulk operations since it brings all data from the database to the client. This adds a lot of overhead if you want to do this for a lot of entities if you don't need to/want to process them on the client. (Note I have not really looked into your code - it's too much)